# Compact operator in squence spaces $T(u) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u_k}{n+k}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

I'm trying to prove the following statement with $E = \ell^2$ with usual norm $||x||_{\ell^2}$ and complex coefficients. Define $T:E \to E$ such that
$$
u = (u_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \mapsto T(u) = \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{u_k}{n+k}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}
$$
show that $T$ isn't a compact operator.

My attepm:
Define a sequence $(w_n^m)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $w_n^m$ weakly converge to $0$ but $T(w_n)$ diverge. For example, let
$$
w^m = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}e_n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(1,\ldots,1,0,\ldots).
$$
the sequence is one until the $m$ position. Actually, $w_n$ weakly converge to $0$ but I can't prove that the image diverge. Any suggestion? Also, if anyone could suggest bibliography about this kind of operators I would be appreciated

UPDATE: I correct the statement of the excercise.

UPDATE 2: Note that

\begin{align} T(w^m) & = \left(\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{w_n^m}{k+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \\ & = \left(\sum_{k=1}^m \frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\cdot\frac{1}{k+n}\right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\\ & = \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} (\psi(m+n+1)-\psi(n+1)) \right)_{n\in\mathbb{N}} \\ \end{align}

where $\psi$ is the digamma function. Can I argue that for each $n$
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}} (\psi(m+n+1)-\psi(n+1)) \to \infty
$$
I'm not sure about properties of digamma function.

Comment: What is the definition of $||x||$?

Comment: Definitions are not clear. What is the difference between $E$ and $F$?

Comment: @geetha290krm If the norm is the $\ell^2$ norm like I suspect, then $w_n$ is of norm $1$, and not $e_n$... but if it is the $\ell^2$ norm then there's also no reason to distinguish $E$ from $F$ so I'm still unsure? $T$ is also not a linear operator because it's not defined on a vector space...

Comment: @BrunoB You are right. I mistook $(e_n)$ to be the standard basis.

Comment: @Akira sorry for confusion is the usual norm in $\ell^2$

Comment: @geetha290krm I correct the statement

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$
\sum_{j=1}^m \frac{1}{j+n} \geq \int_i^{m+1} \frac{dt}{t+n} \geq \log\left(1+\frac{m}{n+1}\right)
$$
with this

$$
||Tw^m||^2 \geq \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right) \log^2(2)
$$
when $m\to \infty$ following the desire result.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Gave a +1 but I think this answer could be improved with slightly more details for the inequality $\|Tw^m\|^2 \geq \left(\frac{m-1}{m}\right) \log^2(2)$ (by the way, try to use `\| thing \|` instead of `|| thing ||`, it'll look better), and a very quick outline of how you proved that the sequence $(w^m)_m$ weakly converge to $0$. Don't have to add too much, it's just for more clarity. But otherwise what you did is perfectly correct!